# Remove string in python dictionary value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have to remove the string including slash (/) in dictionary.

below is the case where i want remove get/ for key "def"

```
 d = {'abc':'apple', 'def':'get/grape', 'xyz':'mango' }
```

and make it

```
d = {'abc':'apple', 'def':'grape', 'xyz':'mango' }
```

Comment: You can just look up how to modify a dictionary value. At the very least detail what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: question is edited. and

Comment: Use `split('/')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

new_d = {key: re.sub('^.*/', '', val) for key, val in d.iteritems()}
```

Comment: that will replace every value. Just want to modify only d[1]

Comment: d1 ?? btw did you tried this: 

{key: val.split('/', 1)[-1] for key, val in d.iteritems()}